# Dependency injection in Signalr hub singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, ninject

I use Ninject for dependency injection and I have something like this:

```
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public ChatHub(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

But the problem is that Hub is a singleton and creation of UnitOfWork is done only once which means I use the same UnitOfWork object the whole time. Its not like in controllers which are created every time when the request come, so the scope of UnitOfWork is also per request.

My question is can I set that unitOfWork gets instantiated and disposed for every reqesut to Hub, although Hub is singleton?

Comment: use a factory, then that factory will be a singleton, however each time the create method is called it will give you a new instance

Comment: And that create method from factory will be called in every method of Hub?

Comment: how are you creating your unit of work?

Comment: So you want each request to deal with a different instance of `IUnitOfWork`? Do you invoke `IUnitOfWork` from multiple methods inside the `ChatHub`? Why do you want `ChatHub` to be singleton and not per request? Does it contain state that need to be shared among different requests?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork Create();
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        // creation of the unit of work
        return new UnitOfWork();
    }
}
```

In your hub:

```
using (var unitOfWork = this.unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
{
    // use it here
    // i'm assuming that your unit of work implements IDisposable
}
```